# Unable to log into my Google account with automatic control software Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I’m currently developing an automatic control software. I’m doing this in Python, with Selenium. To do so, when I open the internet page, a pop-up page opens to connect to my Google account. The problem is, I can’t connect to my Google account. If anybody knows how to bypass this, or how to already be connected to my Google account once I open the web page, I would be grateful.

I tried to disable the security of the Google page, but nothing changed. Maybe I disabled it on the internet page that I opened and not on the Google page. I don’t know how to check. Here is the important part of the code. If you need more, feel free to ask me :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Créez un objet Service avec le chemin de votre pilote ChromeDriver
s = Service(r'D:\Users\Pria\Documents\Data_Science\Python\XX\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')  

# Créez une nouvelle instance du pilote du navigateur Google Chrome
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=D:\\Users\\guill\\Documents\\Data_Science\\Python\\XX\\user_data")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```